# Image upload process

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form used to upload data to my database.Among the data that will be uploaded is an image that will be associated with the data uploaded.(Uploading an image with the data is required.)At the moment, my image script upload works fine, but i am hoping to make it better/ improve the upload process.

Image Upload Process:

```
if($_POST)
{
    //Sets various variables containing the $_POST data submitted by the form
    //Server-side validation
    //Insert form data into database
    //Get last insert id and saves it in a variable
    if(insert is successful)
    {
        //Checks if $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'] isset,!empty,is_uploaded_file
        //Checks if $_FILES['upload']['size'] < max size allowed
        //Sets image fileuploadpath,createimagetruecolor etc...
        //Saves image(imagejpeg,imagegif,imagepng, etc...)
        //Inserts image filepath in database
    }
    else
    {
        die('error');
    }
}
else
{
    die("error");
}
```

As can be seen above, i am currently processing the image after the form data has been successfully uploaded into the database.While it is **currently working atm**,should anything happen while processing/uploading the image, i will end up with a form that has it's data successfully saved in the database while it's image missing, which would lead to all sorts of undesired problems for me.

I am currently saving the images by dynamically creating the fileuploadpath using the lastinsertid of the successful data insertion prior to processing the image. E.g

```
$uploadpath="..\\data\\user\\****lastinsertid****\\img\\****uploadedimage****";
```

which would require me to process the image after successful data insertion, when i have already gotten the lastinsertid.

Is there any way for me to improve my file upload process so that i will not end up with a database record with missing images should any errors arise?

I would appreciate any inputs,opinions and/or advice

P.S I'm currently using PHP 5.5, MYSQL(PDO), having just started programming not too long ago.I can provide examples of my actual code if needed.

Comment: general tip: always use normal `/`-delimited paths in your PHP code. PHP will auto-translate to ``\``-Windows style paths as needed when it actually goes to talk to the disks. As for dangling records, do it in stages. 1) check if upload succeeded. 2) start transaction + insert skeleton db record 3) process upload. 4) update db record with final information + commit. If something fails at any stage, you delete your files and rollback the transaction.

Comment: *"should anything happen while processing/uploading the image"* what do you expect to happen ?

Comment: @Dagon I'm checking for the image's extension while getimagesize, and will terminate with die() if there is an invalid extension, among other checks. E.g maxsizelimit exceeded, etc

Comment: well don't use DIE, its a hammer, handle errors gracefully

Comment: @Dagon I was under the impression that i should be using DIE to terminate the script since i would not want the script to continue running if it fails any of the checks. If a termination is desired, how would i handle it gracefully?

Comment: @MarcB Thank you for the tip, i'm currently changing my filepaths to  tthe normal / instead of the \ i'm surrently using, as well as looking up transactions on google.May i know why it is better to use the forward slash instead of the backslash?Also, im assuming that by skeleton db record, you mean just some dummy placeholder data?

Comment: yes. just insert enough data to create your auto_insert id or whatever you need to process the upload.